PDF Forms: Modify spacing of characters in text fields
I was wondering how to modify the spacing of text in text fields in interactive pdf forms.
Adobe's pdf manual (section 12.7.5.3) does not give any information about the spacing of individual characters, nor does AcroForms (see appendices), but somehow it must be possible...
Here is an example (SEPA credit transfer form):
In the first image (Link to PDF), the spacing of the text in the IBAN text field is incorrect, while the spacing in the second image (Link to PDF) has been changed and now fits exactly into the corresponding gaps:


You need a Comb field with a specific number of chars. E.g.
\DocumentMetadata{lang=en}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{l3pdffield-testphase}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\pdffield_textfield:n{width=10cm,MaxLen=20,setFf=Comb}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}


